# Hover over IBOutlets to find corresponding item in the Main Storyboard in Xcode (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, iboutlet

I'm not totally sure but I thought it was possible in the past to find the corresponding interface element in the storyboard while hovering over the circle in front of an IBOutlet in the code view while you are in the Assistent Editor. I found a screenshot of an **older version** of Xcode.

[image]

But this somehow doesn't work anymore (Xcode 7.1.1 7B1005, Xcode 7.2 beta 4 7C62b and 10.10.5)

[image]

Is there another way to quickly find the connection between IBOutlets and their interface element except for their names?

Comment: Works fine for me (Xcode 7.1.1, Mac OS X 10.11.1)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Xcode to Xcode7, because it's working on that